# ENOENT aparece en la consola del Visual Studio cuando quiero crear una aplicación con React

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
Brayan Farfan@DESKTOP-R38TQ0U MINGW64 /h/React/river
$ create-react-app river

Creating a new React app in H:\React\river\river.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Brayan Farfan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\5.0\\bin',
  path: 'C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\5.0\\bin',
  spawnargs: [
    '/d',
    '/s',
    '/c',
    '"npm ^"install^" ^"--save^" ^"--save-exact^" ^"--loglevel^" ^"error^" ^"react^" ^"react-dom^" ^"react-scripts@0.9.x^""'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No termino de entender el error basado en mongoDB.

Cuando creas un proyecto nuevo con react, en principio, no instalas dependencias de mongodb ni mongoose, esto lo instalas después en la parte del Server.

Te recomiendo:

1º Instalar nodeJS,
2º Instalar NPM, en tu máquina y después.
3º Usar el comando que nos pasa la documentación de React desde el Terminal:

```
npx create-react-app my-app.
```

Donde my-app es el nombre del proyecto que quieres crear.

Un Saludo

Comment: osea, yo estaba haciendo una base de datos con mongo, cuando termine de hacerla, comence hacer otros proyectos sin mongo solo con react, y cuando intento correr la app de react, no me corre, y me salta ese error

Comment: Has probado creando la nueva app en un directorio o carpeta  diferente? o en otro disco?